# Keeping ampersand & in filenames when extracting zip files

Tags: macos, google-apps, unicode, archive-utility

I want to copy my Google Drive folders to an external USB. Google prepares a zip file for me but if I extract that zip file, the & character in filenames are replaced with _. I don't want such a change. I tried the unzip in terminal window, The Unarchiver app and Mac's Archive Utility. Nothing creates the original filenames. Any suggestions?

PS. I can't mirror sync Google Drive onto external disk directly unfortunately. I creates a hyperlink in the external drive and downloads everything onto a local folder. I don't have enough space to mirror the whole Drive. And there is no way to choose which folders to mirror. It is either nothing or all. How inconvenient everything is while my free 1 TB quota is running out.

Comment: Answers shouldnt't be included into questions, please post it as an answer below instead (and maybe add some details about what the command does).

Comment: I now use this command and no issues so far:
ditto is doing everything properly ditto -V -x -k --sequesterRsrc --rsrc FILENAME.ZIP DESTINATIONDIRECTORY

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [BetterZip](https://macitbetter.com) $25 or [Keka](https://www.keka.io/en/) (freeware direct or $5 Apple Store).

Both are considerably more flexible than the built-in options on Mac. BetterZip can show you the file contents before you unzip too.